# Data from my IoT node isn't displayed

Tags: lora, adafruit

I have a LoRa module called Adafruit Feather M0. I tried programming with Arduino in order to eventually display data. The data doesn't show up.

What I've done is that I've registered my LoRa device on the things network, and also connected this device from the things network to Yggio database. It uses MQTTS.

I then downloaded Adafruit boards etc in the Arduino IDE and ran the Feather M0 example code for "hello world" and modified this code with my device ID etc. But it still doesn't work to see the hello world message. The Yggio database is supposed to be connected to a gateway.

Does anyone know if I've missed something in order to display the data?

Comment: There can be many things, you should provide more info (wiring diagram, your code). I also think this question is better suited on Arduino SE

Comment: I don't think here is much information to work with. This is not an electronics design question any more, it's more general. What kind of answer do you expect, do you want to have your hardware debugged? Or software? Have you checked the IP address and firewall settings? As it is now, it's too broad.